# Problems with facebook-android-sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I am following this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started but after importing the samples I get many errors. I had to install other version of eclipse and two different version of the facebook-android-sdk since version 3.15.0 did not have the bin folder to install the Facebook app on the emulator. The errors I get are the following: (note that adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\ was the eclipse previous version, I had to install a new one since the old one was not working properly anymore).

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    SwitchUserSample            Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    GraphApiSample          Unknown Java Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library   'C:\Users\USER\Desarrollo\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar' FacebookSDK     Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-   3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'   HelloFacebookSample     Build path  Build Path   Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    RPSSample       Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    Scrumptious     Unknown Java Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'  GraphApiSample      Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'  Scrumptious     Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    ProfilePictureSample        Unknown Java Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'  RPSSample       Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    SessionLoginSample      Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    PlacePickerSample       Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    NativeAdSample      Unknown Java Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'  PlacePickerSample       Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'  ProfilePictureSample        Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    AdUnitsSample       Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    HelloFacebookSample     Unknown Java Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Desarrollo\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'   NativeAdSample      Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'  FriendPickerSample      Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Desarrollo\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools\support\annotations.jar'   AdUnitsSample       Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'  SessionLoginSample      Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\USER\Dropbox\PruebaTandem\facebook-android-sdk-3.14.1\facebook\bin\facebooksdk.jar'  SwitchUserSample        Build path  Build Path Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    FacebookSDK     Unknown Java Problem
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    FriendPickerSample       Unknown    Java Problem
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and solved it as follows:

- Go to  android-sdk\extras\android\support\annotations and copy **android-support-annotations.jar**     and paste it in **android-sdk\tools\support**.
- Rename to annotations
- Just close all sample projects that is referencing FacebookSDK, clean and build FacebookSDK, facebooksdk.jar will be created.